# Hide React.js component in React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am creating a `React Native` app through `WebView` of my current website which is developed in `React`. There are some components which I do not want to show on the App, I want to hide that. Is there any option to do that.

I tried with `injectedJavaScript` function. Find the div class of the component through web browser and make it hide through `document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].style.display='none'`

This works on browser but not on my ReactNative WebView. Is there any way to disable component of react.js in React Native WebView ?

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your injected script inside an immediately-invoked function like this

```
const injectedScript = `
     (function () {
         // add an alert to make sure that the script is executed
         alert('Holla amigo')
         // you code 
     })();`
```